# Подключение txt файла как массив к python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Есть у меня файл txt где находится 30 тысяч строк различных данных. Можно ли как нибудь из него сделать массив и подключить к python? И сделать чтобы после каждая строка в файла была так же отдельной строкой в массиве.

Comment: Конечно, можно.

Comment: Можно, но на чистом питоне получится список, а не массив. Что вы потом с этим всем хотите делать?

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать телеграм бота который информацию по некоторым данным

Answer (score 3):

Напрашивается такое:

```py
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    rows_list = file.readlines()
    # нужно не забыть, что строка читается вместе с символом перевода строки, тоесть '\n'
    # если этого нужно избежать то:
    rows_list = list(map(str.rstrip, file.readlines()))
    # но это также уберет и все пробельные символы из конца строки
```

Comment: `[i.rstrip() for i in file.readlines()]` -- pep8

Comment: `readlines` не обязательно. Итерация по `file` уже будет возвращать строки, память сэкономите.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов +1

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, спасибо за дельные уточнения. Ответ оставлю как есть, думаю что Ваших комментариев к нему будет достаточно.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica спасибо за дельные уточнения. Ответ оставлю как есть, думаю что Ваших комментариев к нему будет достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    arr = [i.rstrip() for i in f]
```

Comment: движок сайта помещает такие ответы в очередь «сообщения низкого качества». чтобы ответ стал более полезен, дополните его, пожалуйста, пояснениями.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нормальный ответ.